# Tilt background image only

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to tilt the background image only, but I have created it as the outer element so now the whole outer element tilts instead of the image only. I am not experienced in web development so any help or advice appreciated. Below is the code snippet and here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/protonus/p1fzvvuL/2/)

```css
.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-main {
  background: url('http://www.diong.co.uk/laurentino/wp-content/themes/laurentinoazavedo/assets/img/poppy.png') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 30%;
  -moz-background-size: 30%;
  -o-background-size: 30%;
  background-size: 30%;
  /*    height: 100vh;*/
  text-align: center;
  background-position: right;
  background-color: #EDEAE3;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.gallery-main:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.about-main {
  background: url('http://www.diong.co.uk/laurentino/wp-content/themes/laurentinoazavedo/assets/img/orchid.png') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 30%;
  -moz-background-size: 30%;
  -o-background-size: 30%;
  background-size: 30%;
  /* height: 100vh; */
  text-align: center;
  background-position: left;
  background-color: #EFEDE6;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.about-main:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#">
  <section class="gallery-main">
    <div class="container-fluid vertical-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-8">
          <h2>GALLERY</h2>
          <p>We create everlasting memories.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- end col -->
      </div>
      <!-- row -->
    </div>
  </section>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <section class="about-main">
    <div class="container-fluid vertical-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-10">
          <h2>ABOUT</h2>
          <p class="larger-font">Working with natural wonders to illustrate the clean lines of modern design.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- end col -->
      </div>
      <!-- row -->
    </div>
    <!-- hero -->
  </section>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First that you need is reassign background to another tag, it shouldn't be a wrapper of this section (for example you can use pseudo elements like :before or :after).

and your code should looks like:

```
.gallery-main {
   position: relative
/* Don't use rotate effect for section wrapper */
}

.gallery-main:before{

  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

   background: url('http://www.diong.co.uk/laurentino/wp-content/themes/laurentinoazavedo/assets/img/poppy.png') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 30%;
  -moz-background-size: 30%;
  -o-background-size: 30%;
  background-size: 30%;
  background-position: right;
  background-color: #EDEAE3;

text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.gallery-main:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

working code for first section you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p1fzvvuL/3/)

Comment: That is what I have been battling with, trying to figure out how to assign the background to a different tag, or reassigning the tags to only have the flower tilt and not the whole section tag.

Comment: See the code sample above. I assigned background to pseudo element :before for your first section. Also you can see live example at https://jsfiddle.net/p1fzvvuL/3/

Comment: Thank You @Ihor, how would I go about making the flower tilt and not the whole background. I don't want to see the white parts of the background.

Comment: I think you can use the same background-color for your section wrapper, as on the photo. I found it. It's #edeae3;
You can have a look at my fiddle. I've already updated it.  
have a look at this fiddle jsfiddle.net/p1fzvvuL/4